# How to add a separator between UIImageViews in UIScrollView and keep the paging scroll height 480?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have a `UIScrollView` that contains 2 `UIImageViews`. I turn on the pagination properties and am able to scroll vertical pages (480). Now I want to add another `UIImageView` that will act as separator between the images and keep the vertical scrolling height. Means that every time I'll scroll, I'll see the separator but stop on the full image. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to scroll the UIScrollView and keep the separator static on the screen over the UIScrollView?  If yes, then you can just add the separator view (whatever it is) to the main view, not to the UIScrollView - but add it after the UIScrollView - so that it would be displayed over it.

Answer (score 0):

This `UIView` method might do the trick: [hitTest:withEvent:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent:)
See [UIScrollView Custom Paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945964/uiscrollview-custom-paging)

Comment: As long as the interaction feels natural, why not.